# SharePoint 2013 error not loading ribbon and can't activate features

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a new sharepoint web application and i the ribbon doesn't load for both lists

and libraries.I also can't activate any feature.

Trying also to figure out why i can't crawl and search a particular web collection.
Thanks in Advance.
Errors I'm getting inb IE below:

```
start.aspx
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize empty string.
Parameter name: data 

ScriptResource.axd, line 5 character 50445
SEC7126: Redirects are not allowed for CORS preflight requests. 
start.aspx
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

start.aspx
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize empty string.
Parameter name: data 
ScriptResource.axd, line 5 character 50445
```